# Create a Dropdown Selector and Redirect for a Custom Taxonomy in WordPress?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-taxonomy, javascript, dropdown

I'm trying to create a dropdown selector on my CPT and CT archive page for a custom taxonomy called "location".

I've managed to get the form to submit, however, **it does not direct me to the archive page, rather it directs me to a URL that looks something like this**

> https://example.com/?location=11

**I'm wanting the destination URL to be this:**

> https://example.com/location/term-name

Bare with me as I have no background in Computer Science / IT so I'm learning on my own.

Below is my shortcode to insert it into my website. I have taken portions of this code from WordPress' Category Dropdown Selector and modified it for my Custom Taxonomy.

```
function insert_location(){
    ob_start();
?>
<form action="https://example.com" method="get">
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="location">Locations</label>
    <select name="location" id="location" class="postform">
        <?php
           $tax_terms = get_terms('location', array('hide_empty' => '0'));      
           foreach ( $tax_terms as $tax_term ):  
              echo '<option value="-1">Select a Location</option>
                    <option class="level-0" value="'.$tax_term->term_id.'">'.$tax_term->name.'</option>';   
           endforeach;
        ?>
    </select> 
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">  
/* <![CDATA[ */
(function() {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById( "location" );
    function onLocChange() {
        if ( dropdown.options[ dropdown.selectedIndex ].value > 0 ) {
            dropdown.parentNode.submit();
        }
    }
    dropdown.onchange = onLocChange;
})();
/* ]]> */
</script>
<?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('location_filter','insert_location');
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated in helping me to create a dropdown selector that takes visitors to the correct URL, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind!

I managed to come up with a solution.

```
function insert_location(){
    ob_start();
?>
    <select name="location" id="location" class="postform">
        <?php
           $tax_terms = get_terms('location', array('hide_empty' => '0'));      
           foreach ( $tax_terms as $tax_term ):  
              echo '<option value="-1">Select a Location</option><option class="level-0" value="'.get_term_link($tax_term).'">'.$tax_term->name.'</option>';   
           endforeach;
        ?>
    </select> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    
/* <![CDATA[ */
(function() {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById( "location" );
    function onLocChange() {
        if ( dropdown.options[ dropdown.selectedIndex ].value != "-1" ) {
            window.location.href = dropdown.options[ dropdown.selectedIndex ].value;
        }
    }
    dropdown.onchange = onLocChange;
})();
/* ]]> */
</script>
<?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('location_filter','insert_location');
```

Instead of using the Term ID, I have replaced it with

```
.get_term_link($tax_term).
```

And rather than submitting with a form, I have chosen to use the following line of code.

```
window.location.href = dropdown.options[ dropdown.selectedIndex ].value;
```